# spring oauth2: access_token isn't in response after succefull request

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security, oauth-2.0

i try to authenticated a user on my rest-api with oauth2. But i didn't get the access_token in response after a succefull request.

A part of code:

My ServerConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class OAuth2ServerConfiguration {

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("clientsecret")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("password")
                    .authorities("USER")
                    .scopes("read")
                    .secret("12345")
                    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(60);
            // @formatter:on
        }
    }
}
```

my securityconfiguration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
        builder
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity security) throws Exception {
        security.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/oauth/token")
            .hasRole("USER")
            .and().httpBasic().realmName("OAuth Server");
    }
```

my controller:

```
@Path("/oauth")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class TestController {

    @GET
    @Path("/token")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response testToken() {

        return Response.status(200).entity("is working fine \n")
        .header("Server", "Apache Tomcat/8.0.20")
        .header("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .header("Connection", "Opened")
        .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
    }
}
```

my request:

```
curl -X GET -k -vu user:password http://localhost:8080/test/oauth/token -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "grant_type=password&scope=read&client_secret=12345&client_id=clientsecret"
```

and my response:

```
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'user'
> GET /test/oauth/token HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> Authorization: Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> Content-Length: 73
> 
* upload completely sent off: 73 out of 73 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=0D30F02C6F9A194786581A6C0EB20909; Path=/test/; HttpOnly
< Server: Apache Tomcat/8.0.20
< Connection: Opened
< Content-Type: application/json
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Thu, 10 Sep 2015 10:12:39 GMT
< 
is working fine 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

what i have to do to see the access_token in response. Why i did get it in json format?

Thank for response.
Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

To request an OAuth 2.0 token you have to do a `POST` request to the endpoint and include username/pass/grant type in the request body. Something like this:

```
curl -u clientsecret:12345 -X POST http://localhost:8080/oauth/token -H "Accept:application/json" -d "username=user&password=password&grant_type=password"
```

Comment: i try it with your request but a got this: username=user&password=password&grant_type=passwordis working fine  and not the access_token. When i give a wrong password in the parameter, i receive the same response. Is it normal? something like: curl ...-d "username=US&password=PASS&grant_type=password"

Comment: Why did you define a controller to handle `/oauth/token`? Those endpoints are exposed automatically by `spring-security-oauth2`. You don't need to manually handle them.

Comment: when i don't use a controller a call the request on /oauth/token, i got a 404 error. when i don't handle the request in testToken method i got nothing in response.

Comment: You're probably doing something wrong in your implementation, @EnableAuthorizationServer should enable those endpoints to you. I advise you to read more on how to use spring-oauth2. Check this link to see examples for AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter and ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter http://pastebin.com/qSajEZsR